# Python - Unpivot data

Tags: python, pandas

Looking for a python solution. Need assistance in unpivoting a data frame in `python`. The structure is a little funky for a basic pivot function for how I'd like to reshape it.

CURRENT DATA FRAME - Here's what I have

```
ABC Mechanical              

              Standard  15-Day  10-Day  5-Day
Terminal Units  0.49    0.75    0.69    0.63
Diffusers       0.35    0.55    0.45    0.4
Vent            0.8     0.95    0.9     0.85
Piping          0.7     0.85    0.8     0.75
Stoves          0.6     0.8     0.75    0.7
```

UNPIVOTED DATA FRAME - Here's how I want to reshape it

```
df.columns= Customer, Product Category, Ship Cycle, Multiplier
df.index= ABC Mechanical 

Customer    Product Category    Ship Cycle  Multiplier
ABC Mechanical  Terminal Units  Standard    0.49
ABC Mechanical  Terminal Units  15-Day      0.75
ABC Mechanical  Terminal Units  10-Day      0.69
ABC Mechanical  Terminal Units  5-Day       0.63
ABC Mechanical  Diffusers       Standard    0.35
ABC Mechanical  Diffusers       15-Day      0.55
ABC Mechanical  Diffusers       10-Day      0.45
ABC Mechanical  Diffusers       5-Day       0.4
```

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: "I've attempted utilizing `pd.melt()`" isn't a helpful statment. Show us what you tried.

Comment: @pnuts a python solution. Sorry about the inaccurate data, I've updated the df.

Comment: @PaulH I didn't post my attempts, because I'm not sure if an `unpivot` method is the way to go with this. So I am reaching out for suggestions on best approach

Comment: A copy/paste-able example demonstrating what you've tried is always helpful. Since you want a python solution, leave out the bit about excel since it's not longer relevant. Start with the data you get after reading the data.

Comment: Where is "ABC Mechanical" supposed to come from?  Is that the name of your index column?  (I can't tell from your current data frame picture where that name is being stored.)

Comment: @DSM "ABC Mechanical" is shown at the top of the original df. That's one of my issues with the structure in trying to reshape the data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `df` looks like this:

```
In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
                Standard  15-Day  10-Day  5-Day
Terminal Units      0.49    0.75    0.69   0.63
Diffusers           0.35    0.55    0.45   0.40
Vent                0.80    0.95    0.90   0.85
Piping              0.70    0.85    0.80   0.75
Stoves              0.60    0.80    0.75   0.70
```

then `pd.melt` gets you close to the desired DataFrame:

```
In [27]: pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars=['index']).sort_values(by=['index'])
Out[27]: 
             index  variable  value
1        Diffusers  Standard   0.35
6        Diffusers    15-Day   0.55
11       Diffusers    10-Day   0.45
16       Diffusers     5-Day   0.40
3           Piping  Standard   0.70
8           Piping    15-Day   0.85
13          Piping    10-Day   0.80
18          Piping     5-Day   0.75
4           Stoves  Standard   0.60
9           Stoves    15-Day   0.80
14          Stoves    10-Day   0.75
19          Stoves     5-Day   0.70
0   Terminal Units  Standard   0.49
5   Terminal Units    15-Day   0.75
10  Terminal Units    10-Day   0.69
15  Terminal Units     5-Day   0.63
2             Vent  Standard   0.80
7             Vent    15-Day   0.95
12            Vent    10-Day   0.90
17            Vent     5-Day   0.85
```

I don't understand where "ABC Mechanical" is in the original DataFrame, so I haven't attempted to include it in the result. The column names can renamed like this:

```
In [28]: df = pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars=['index']).sort_values(by=['index'])
In [29]: df.columns = ['Product Category', 'Ship Cycle', 'Multiplier']
In [31]: df.head()
Out[31]: 
   Product Category Ship Cycle  Multiplier
1         Diffusers   Standard        0.35
6         Diffusers     15-Day        0.55
11        Diffusers     10-Day        0.45
16        Diffusers      5-Day        0.40
3            Piping   Standard        0.70
```

Comment: Not that it matters much, but I tend to use `var_name` and `value_name` when unmelting.  Can't think of a clever way to change the `index` column name, though.

Comment: @unutbu "ABC Mechanical" is shown at the top left of the original df, but thank you for this response. This is very insightful. I'm still learning the power of the Pandas library.

Comment: @MikeV.: Please edit the question to include `df.columns` and `df.index`. That might give us a clue what `ABC Mechanical` is.

Comment: ".sort" is ".sort_values" in pandas 0.22

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `unstack()`:

```
In [41]:

print df
                Standard  15-Day  10-Day  5-Day
Terminal_Units      0.49    0.75    0.69   0.63
Diffusers           0.35    0.55    0.45   0.40
Vent                0.80    0.95    0.90   0.85
Piping              0.70    0.85    0.80   0.75
Stoves              0.60    0.80    0.75   0.70
In [42]:

df2 = df.stack().reset_index()
df2.columns = ['Product Category',    'Ship Cycle',  'Multiplier']
df2['Customer'] = 'ABC Mechanical'
In [43]:

print df2.icol([3,0,1,2])
          Customer Product Category Ship Cycle  Multiplier
0   ABC Mechanical   Terminal_Units   Standard        0.49
1   ABC Mechanical   Terminal_Units     15-Day        0.75
2   ABC Mechanical   Terminal_Units     10-Day        0.69
3   ABC Mechanical   Terminal_Units      5-Day        0.63
4   ABC Mechanical        Diffusers   Standard        0.35
5   ABC Mechanical        Diffusers     15-Day        0.55
6   ABC Mechanical        Diffusers     10-Day        0.45
7   ABC Mechanical        Diffusers      5-Day        0.40
8   ABC Mechanical             Vent   Standard        0.80
9   ABC Mechanical             Vent     15-Day        0.95
10  ABC Mechanical             Vent     10-Day        0.90
11  ABC Mechanical             Vent      5-Day        0.85
12  ABC Mechanical           Piping   Standard        0.70
13  ABC Mechanical           Piping     15-Day        0.85
14  ABC Mechanical           Piping     10-Day        0.80
15  ABC Mechanical           Piping      5-Day        0.75
16  ABC Mechanical           Stoves   Standard        0.60
17  ABC Mechanical           Stoves     15-Day        0.80
18  ABC Mechanical           Stoves     10-Day        0.75
19  ABC Mechanical           Stoves      5-Day        0.70
```