# Most elegant way to transform this type of table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
id   name   last   attribute_1_name  attribute_1_rating  attribute_2_name  attribute_2_rating
 1   Linda  Smith  Age                23                  Hair              Brown
 3   Brian  Lin    Hair               Black               Job               Barista
```

Essentially I'd like to transform this table to look like so:

```
id   name   last   attribute_name  attribute_rating
 1   Linda  Smith  Age                23
 1   Linda  Smith  Hair               Brown
 3   Brian  Lin    Hair               Black
 3   Brian  Lin    Job                Barista
```

What's the most elegant and efficient way to perform this transformation in Python? Assuming there are many more rows and the attribute numbers go up to 13.

Comment: Have a look at other answers on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640715/3087542

Comment: Thanks, @quizzical_panini, the linked thread is a bit of a simpler problem as it just transforms from wide to long. I am looking to work with the numeric named columns and push them into one for each unique type of variable.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming attribute columns are named coherently, you can do this:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()

# n is the number of attribute columns
for i in range(1, n):
    attribute_name_col = f'attribute_{i}_name'
    attribute_rating_col = f'attribute_{i}_rating'
    melted = pd.melt(
        df, 
        id_vars=['id', 'name', 'last', attribute_name_col], 
        value_vars=[attribute_rating_col]
    )
    melted = melted.rename(
        columns={attribute_name_col: 'attribute_name', 
                 'value': 'attribute_rating'}
    )
    melted = melted.drop('variable', axis=1)
    result = pd.concat([result, melted])
```

where `df` is your original dataframe. Then printing `result` gives

```
id  name    last      attribute_name    attribute_rating
1   Linda   Smith     Age               23
3   Brian   Lin       Hair              Black
1   Linda   Smith     Hair              Brown
3   Brian   Lin       Job               Barista
```

Comment: how would this work with multiple attributes (more than 2)?

Comment: Replace `for i in [1, 2]` with `for i in range(1, n)` (I edited my answer accordingly).